# Difference when declare variable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class below:

```
@interface Person : NSObject {
  NSString *_firstname;
}
@property NSString *firstName;
@end

@implementation Person

@synthesize firstname;

@end
```

This will declare three variables: firstname, self.firstname and _firstname

What is the difference between the three variables and how do you using with each case?

Comment: The main thing you need to know is that this way of doing things is outdated and not needed anymore and hasn't been needed for some time. The only variable declaration you need to know is the `@property` version as this will auto generate the `ivar` (`_firstname`) and the `@synthesize` for you which automatically produces cleaner easier to read code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern Objective-C you don't need to create instance variable if you already synthesizing properties.
From what you write it appears that you are confusing properties and ivar.
Properties create getters and setters to your ivars, but they are not ivars, they are methods that access you ivars to set or get their values.
Your class can be sum up like that:

```
@interface Person : NSObject 
@property NSString *firstName;
@end

@implementation Person

@end
```

At compile time this will ensure that you can access your ivar using methods and name your ivar as `_firstName`.
Dot notation create access to properties so `self.firstName` (using ARC and default property option -nonatomic,strong-)calls that method

```
- (NSString*)firstName 
{
    return _firstName;
}
```

While calling `self.firstName = @"foo";` calls:

```
- (void) setFirstName:(NSString*)name 
{
    if (_firstName == name) {
        return;
    }
    _firstName = name;
}
```

Underlining implementation could be a little different.

Answer (score 0):

The first one  `NSString *_firstname;` is an instance variable. The @property is a property which is syntesized (you don't have to manually synthesize properties in modern Objective-C). When you declare a property you can access its instance variable with _propertyName or with self.propertyName.

It is up to you whether you declare your variables as instance variables or as properties but it is more common and suggested to declare them as properties (using properties you can have access to getters and setters, which means that you can run code before the value of the property will be set or will be read).

Answer (score 0):

You can chain instance with property using

```
@interface Person : NSObject {
   NSString *_firstname;
}
@property NSString *firstName;
@end

@implementation Person

@synthesize firstName = _firstname;

@end
```

Both pointers are pointing same instance now.

Comment: what's happend if i not assign firstname=_firstname. and what's different between self.firstname and firstname

Comment: if you dont bind them the both pointers would different and they can point to different instances.

like self.firstName = @"Name1"
_firstName = @"Name2" Name2 is private to your class that is not exposed to other